# Gymnastics Rings vs Triangles

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, push-ups, pull-ups, rings

I have a set of triangle shaped resistance band handles ([like this](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fecx.images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F41WsXu2Dy8L._SY300_.jpg&f=1&nofb=1)) that I've been using for pushups and pullups to make the exercise more difficult and to build up stabilizer muscles.

Is there any reason to buy gymnastics rings instead, if I'm just doing the basics?

Edit: Each triangle has two [box stitches](https://youtu.be/wf6buu7PqT4?t=49) on it, so I presume that is more than strong enough for my body weight. Has anyone ever had one of these break catastrophically?

Comment: Are they cheaper or something? Because straps and rings are two separate components and neither has to be expensive. Don't forget dips and holds. Those are good for stabilizers too.

Comment: Similar question here: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/43043/are-there-any-advantages-of-round-gymnastic-rings-over-flattened

Answer (score 2):

One benefit of rings is that if you get a strap that can have multiple attachments points (I use a rogue strap looped upward and clipped to itself mid-way to capture the first pair of rings before continuing down again to capture more rings)  so that the remainder goes back down even lower), you can have multiple pairs of rings along the length so that there is always a pair available or pull-ups, dips, or push-ups. No need to fiddle with readjusting. It makes a big difference.

Also, you can only false grip on the rings.

Are those triangles designed to support your full body weight? I am a bit skeptical, and I'm only 120lbs.

Comment: That's a good point about body weight. Fully clothed, I'm 220 pounds so I worry about the triangles breaking. They came free with my old tubular bands kit, but I don't know the rating.

Comment: Can you expand on your point about "false grip" - Is that only for muscle ups?

Comment: @SurpriseDog As far as I know they're only for muscle-ups but I'm pretty sure they're used for a lot more than that, but that is wandering into the stuff you see in the gymnastic ring competitions at the Olympics.